# Fill ListView control with ADODB.Connection Query Results?

Tags: c#, listview, db2, database-connection, adodb

This is my first time trying to connect to a AS400 system, and somewhere along the lines I am failing. Below is my current code I have put together based off a few sample applications. Currently my code is failing at `recordList.Open()` with message:

```
Execption Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
Message: ODBC driver does not suppor tthe requested properties.
Data: System.Collections.ListDIctionaryInternal
```

I'm attempting to query the AS400, and use my results to fill a Windows Forms ListView control. Clearly I am overlooking or doing something wrong. Can someone more experience in this sort of thing spot where I'm messing up?

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;


namespace MemberRecordChange
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.dtpDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmbLetterType.Items.Add("Address Change (old address)(Active/Inactive member)");
            cmbLetterType.Items.Add("Address Change (old address)(Benefit Recipeint)");
            cmbLetterType.Items.Add("Address Change (new address)(Active/Inactive member)");
            cmbLetterType.Items.Add("Address Change (new address)(Benefit Recipeint)");
            cmbLetterType.Items.Add("Name Change Letter");
            cmbLetterType.Items.Add("Welcome Letter");
            cmbLetterType.Items.Add("Nomination of Beneficiary Form");

            //~~~~~~~~~~~~This is for debugging purposes. I have other code between this step and the function being called below, but first I need to fill the ListView control~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            GetiSeriesData("test", "test", "MY-FULL-QUERY");
        }

        private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            .......
        }

        public void GetiSeriesData(string docLoc, string docSource, string query)
        {
            DataTable addresses = new DataTable();
            DataTable changes = new DataTable();

            string connString = string.Format("DRIVER=Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit); SYSTEM=XX.XX.X.XX; UID=XXXXX; PWD=XXXXX");

            ADODB.Connection conn = new ADODB.Connection();
            ADODB.Recordset recordList = new ADODB.Recordset();
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            ADODB.Command cmd = new ADODB.Command();

            string memName = "";
            string startTime = this.dtpDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "-00.00.00.000000";
            string endTime = this.dtpDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "-23.59.00.000000";

            try
            {
                conn.Open(connString, null, null, 0);
                //????
                cmd.ActiveConnection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                //addresses.Clear();
                //da.Fill(addresses);


                // EXCEPTION THROWN ON BELOW LINE

                recordList.Open(query, conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic, 1);



                // CODE EXECUTION DOES NOT REACH THE BELOW

                if (!recordList.EOF)
                {
                    memName = recordList.Fields["NAME"].Value.ToString();
                    lvData.View = View.Details;
                    Int16 x = 0;
                    while (!recordList.EOF)
                    {
                        lvData.Items.Add(recordList.Fields["MEMNO"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["NAME"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["ADDR1"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["ADDR2"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["CITY"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["STATE"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["ZIP"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["OLD_ADDR1"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["OLD_ADDR2"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["OLD_CITY"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["OLD_STATE"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(recordList.Fields["OLD_ZIP"].Value.ToString().Trim());
                        x += 1;

                        recordList.MoveNext();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No records found");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
            }
            finally
            {
                recordList.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Figured part of it out, haven't gotten the .SubItems to show up in the control yet:

```
 string connString = "DRIVER=Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit); SYSTEM=XX.XX.X.XX; UID=XXXX; PWD=XXXX";

            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connString;
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (!dr.HasRows)
            {
                throw new Exception("No records found.");
            }

            Int16 x = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                lvData.Items.Add(dr["memno"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["NAME"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ADDR1"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ADDR2"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["CITY"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["STATE"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ZIP"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ADDR1"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ADDR2"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_CITY"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_STATE"].ToString().Trim());
                lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ZIP"].ToString().Trim());
            x += 1;
            }
```

Comment: Does the following post help 'http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/handling-threadabortexception-with.html'

Comment: @PeterSchuetze, not really.That appears to be for Web Forms or the like, whereas this is a simple C# Windows Forms Application. Also, for anyone who might try to view the link you posted, you accidentally included the apostrophe character at the end of the link, so the link will not navigate correctly unless you copy link/paste/remove the apostrophe character.