# How to query 400 System and use results as DataSource for ListView Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, database-connection, db2-400

I'm developing a simple C# Windows Forms Applicaiton. Can someone provide me with examples of how to:

1. Open connection to AS400 system
2. Use a string to query the opened connection.
3. Store query results in some manner.
4. Use the stored results as DataSource for a ListView Control

I don't have a preference 1 way or the other (nor know the difference) between ODBC and ADO methods for accomplishing this, but my current efforts are failing sharply. For anyone interested, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868926/fill-listview-control-with-adodb-connection-query-results?noredirect=1#comment29625129_19868926) is my current code which seems to be missing an important step somewhere, hence why I'm seeking examples.

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Figured it out:

```
 string connString = "DRIVER=Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit); SYSTEM=XX.XX.X.XX; UID=XXXX; PWD=XXXX";

            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connString;
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (!dr.HasRows)
            {
                throw new Exception("No records found.");
            }

            Int16 x = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ....
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the links in the post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7292a82f-e4f7-4849-aaef-2e16cee159c8/how-to-access-as400-system-from-c-net-2008

Comment: I've reviewed the links, but nothing is helping with what I'm after (other than explaining ODBC vs OleDb).

Comment: Are you trying to connect to DB2 or IMS ? For DB2 IBM has dll which can be used to connect to DB2 database, if you are using IMS you will have to use a Queue to connect fire a transaction at IMS and get it back, a lot of effort

Comment: Both of those sound pretty extreme. I'm looking to use ODBC or possibly ADO to connect, query, source, close.

Comment: Not sure if we could do that using ADO or ODBC, if you get a possible solution please share

Comment: I figured out how to do the ODBC, posted in my EDIT above.

Comment: @kh_s the post is titled and tagged as pertaining to DB2 400, now known as DB2 for i. The name AS/400 is about as dated referring to a modern IBM mainframe as a S/370 running DOS-VSE. IBM i OS runs on Power Systems (like Watson was built on) and Pure Systems. It has DB2 integrated into the heart of the OS and the machine itself, not a separate package. IMS may have its place, but is not found on IBM i.

Answer (score 0):

With C#, I would think you would want to use the [.NET Data Provider in IBM i Access for Windows](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikdotnetprovider.htm), to provide the highest level of functionality to your C# program.  But of course you can use [ADO or ODBC](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikcaapidb.htm) directly if you so choose.

In any event, you should probably pay attention to the options available in the [connection settings](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Fconnectkeywords.htm).  Your system administrator may have specific advice, but it generally better practice to use [system naming](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-sqlnaming/), to use the flexibility of library lists (a schema search path).  If they are current on OS updates for v7.1, then system naming does not require adopting '/' syntax.